# jQuery append div with if condition

Tags: jquery

I have this append statement

```
$("#questions").append($("<tr><td>" + if(value.NA == true) { + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + value.Question_ID + "-na' class='na' /> " + } + "</td>");
```

I am trying to add a condition to the append, but I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

I am assuming this if is illegal, what would be the best way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Run the condition first to set the content then append, you can't run an `if` statement like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` cannot be used within strings.

Use a variable to store the HTML and use the variable in the `append`.

```
var input = ''; // Set as empty string

if(value.NA === true) {
    input = "<input type='checkbox' id='" + value.Question_ID + "-na' class='na' /> ";
}

$("#questions").append($("<tr><td>" + input + "</td>"));
```

Ternary operator(`?..:`) can also be used

```
$("#questions").append($("<tr><td>" + (value.NA ? "<input type='checkbox' id='" + value.Question_ID + "-na' class='na' /> " : '') + "</td>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Javascript conditional (ternary) operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp):

```
$("#questions").append($("<tr><td>" + (value.NA ? "<input type='checkbox' id='" + value.Question_ID + "-na' class='na' /> " : "") + "</td>");
```